# Converting Ambiguous Grammar G to LL(1)

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, compilers, parsers, factoring

So I am in the process of learning about LL(1) grammar and converting an ambiguous one into LL(1). I know how to figure out if a grammar (G) is ambiguous, however, I am having trouble converting it to a LL(1) using left factoring.

From my understanding, left factoring is basically factoring out prefixes which are common to two or more productions. So for example,

```
 A -> X | X Y Z
```

Becomes

```
A -> X B
B -> Y Z | ε
```

However, if we take an example such as the following grammar G,

```
A -> acB | da
B -> abB | daA | Af
```

How would I go about applying the left factoring to convert G to LL(1) since there is no common prefix based on what I can see. I am assuming I would have to use substitution (right corner substitution), correct?

The following is my attempt at converting G to LL(1), did I do it correctly?

```
A -> acB | da
B -> abB | daA | Af

A -> acabB | daA | Af | da     //sub B into A

A -> E | Af | da               //left factor
E -> acabB | daA | 1
```